# Firefox plugin development and embedding an .swf in xul with html:embed

Tags: javascript, html, flash, firefox, xul

I have a big problem with my firefox plugin. I have a button, which opens a new window for me, where I want to include that .swf file.

Here is the XUL code for the embedding:

```
<html:embed src="Reader.swf" 
width="250" 
height="250"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

-> html namespace was set above:
`xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`

Reader.swf is in the same directory as the xul file

without the html:embed, the window opens without problems, but as soon as I change that, firefox crashes without warning or something, it just disapears from the process bar.

the .swf file works properly when I open it from my operating system (its windows 7 64 bit) and is coded in as3.

can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing the swf file directly into the new window, try wrapping it in a minimal html page.  Or you could use the html page that flash generates for you when you publish your movie. I haven't played with XUL, but I have noticed that placing swf files directly into browsers is a little inconsistent across browsers.  For example, some browsers will scale the movie to 100% of the available window space, others will not.